# Neutralization reactions

Tags: acid-base

I saw that most neutralization reactions produce water while some do not.

How can I know if water will be a product in a given neutralization reaction?

I initially thought that water is a product only when an acid reacts with an alkali (producing hydroxide ions) but there apparently exist some counterexamples like the reaction between ethanoic acid and copper oxide.

Comment: Your counterexample does give water on neutralization: $\ce{CuO + 2CH3COOH -> Cu(CH3COO)2 + H2O}$

Comment: yeah, so although CuO is not an alkali, it still gives water and that's why it's a counterexample of my initial thought.

Comment: $\ce{CuO}$ is basic in nature. Most metal oxides eg $\ce{CaO}$, $\ce{MgO}$ etc are basic in nature and neutralize acids in aqueous media. These are divalent and the oxygen anion accepts two protons to form $\ce{H2O}$.

Comment: Hint: Ask yourself and try to thoroughly search for an answer, what is an acid, what is a base and when their reactions produce water.

Comment: There are plenty more bases than hydroxide or carbonates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neutralizations of any acid with oxides, hydroxides and carbonates always produce a salt **and water**.

The only neutralizations that do not produce water are reactions of an acid $\ce{HX}$ with ammonia $\ce{NH3}$ or with organic derivates of ammonia, like amines. These reactions produce an ammonium salt $\ce{NH4X}$ and no water
$$\ce{NH3 + HX -> NH4X}$$ If the acid is $\ce{H2Y}$ or $\ce{H3Z}$, the neutralization reactions are $$\ce{2  NH3 + H2Y -> (NH4)2Y}$$ $$\ce{3 NH3 + H3Z -> (NH4)3Z}$$ It never produces $\ce{H2O}$. If one atom $\ce{H}$ from $\ce{NH3}$ is replaced by an organic radical $\ce{R}$, a primary amine $\ce{RNH2}$ is obtained and the neutralization reaction produces also an ammonium salt $\ce{RNH3X}$ $$\ce{RNH2 + HX -> RNH3X}$$ Similar reactions can be obtained with secondary and tertiary amines. All these reactions produce salts and no water.

Comment: Hmm, how about CaO + SiO_2 = CaSiO3? Isn't that considered a neutralization reaction despite not producing water? @Maurice

Comment: @Shane. You are right. The reaction $\ce{CaO + SiO2 -> CaSiO3}$ is considered a neutralization reaction despite not producing water, because both reactants  are reacting with water to produce a hydroxide ($\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ and an acid $\ce{H2SiO3}$. These two last substances do react together according to : $$\ce{Ca(OH)2 + H2SiO3 -> CaSiO3 + 2 H2O}$$ I should have added this comment into my message.

Answer (score 0):

The General Chemistry answer is for any strong base and strong acid there will be a molecule of water produced and a salt.

BOH + HA --> H2O + BA

Giving credit where it is due, @waylander, @Poutnik, @Dongwi Min, and @Aniruddah Deb make excellent assertions regarding your question and I'd refer you to this Quora post (https://www.quora.com/What-is-formed-by-the-reaction-between-metal-oxide-and-water) that talks a bit about productions of metal hydroxides within water.